# Unbinding events in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, dom-events

Let's take `stdin.on` as an example. Callbacks to `stdin.on` stack, so if I write (in CoffeeScript)

```
stdin = process.openStdin()
stdin.setEncoding 'utf8'
stdin.on 'data', (input) -> console.log 'One'
stdin.on 'data', (input) -> console.log 'Two'
```

then every time I hit return at the prompt, I get

```
One
Two
```

My question is, is there any way to remove/replace a callback once bound? Or is the only approach to bind a proxy callback and manage state myself?

Comment: How to remove inline listener functions?
Like `server.on('connect', function(pkt){...});`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `removeListener(eventType, callback)` to remove an event, which should work with all kinds of emitters.

Example from the API docs:

```
var callback = function(stream) {
  console.log('someone connected!');
};
server.on('connection', callback);
// ...
server.removeListener('connection', callback);
```

So you need to have a variable that holds a reference to the callback, because obviously, it's otherwise impossible to tell which callback you want to have removed.

**EDIT**
Should be someone like this in CS:

```
stdin = process.openStdin()
stdin.setEncoding 'utf8'

logger = (input) -> console.log 'One'
stdin.on 'data', logger
stdin.removeListener 'data', logger

stdin.on 'data', (input) -> console.log 'Two'
```

See: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#emitter.removeListener

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: This works well, but is there a way to remove inline listener functions? 

Like `server.on('connect', function(pkt){...});`

Answer (score 18):

Or you can use:

`stdin.once` instead of `stdin.on`