# Cancel .on event listener/callback

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, asynccallback

I have the following code

```js
const broadcastTxn = await web3.eth
  .sendSignedTransaction(txn.signed)
  .on('receipt', (r) => console.log('Receipt', r))
  .on('confirmation', (c) => this.handleConfirmation(c, txn));

...

handleConfirmation(c: number, txn: Transaction): void {
  // do some stuff
}
```

I get multiple `confirmations` returned, but after the 3rd I'd like to cancel the callback/event that continues listening for `.on('confirmation')`

I tried putting logic in the `handleConfirmation` function to throw

```js
handleConfirmation(c: number, txn: Transaction): void {
  // do some stuff
  if (c >= 3) throw new Error('cancelling callback');
}
```

but that doesn't work, it keeps getting called.

What is the correct way to end the `.on('confirmation')` listener?

`es2017 & Node 14.9.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener)

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks for the response. I wouldn't know what object to call `removeEventListener` on. I'm also not explicitly calling `addEventListener` I'm chaining a `.on(..)` function.

Comment: Usually on the same object you added the event. Sometimes you have to break call chains and store objects in variables.

Comment: `await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txn.signed).removeEventListener('confirmation')` does not work unfortunately

Comment: This creates a new object without events. You have to remove the events from the object to added the events. In Node.js it's `off` or `removeListener`: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: That _sounds_ right however I'm not sure how to implement it in my case. Care to post an example?

Comment: You have to break your call chain after `sendSignedTransaction(txn.signed)` and store it in a variable. Here is another link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893872/how-to-properly-remove-event-listeners-in-node-js-eventemitter#

Comment: @ThomasSablik If I do `const broadcastTxn = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txn.signed)`
I am unable to call `broadcastTxn.on('...')` - it throws and error.  I get what you're pointing at but it is unclear to me how I can store that variable so I can reference it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ThomasSablik pointed me in the correct direction. I needed to capture the object without using `await`. Then I could reference it and use `await` afterwards. Solution below

```js
const signedTxnListener = web3.eth
  .sendSignedTransaction(txn.signed)
  .on('receipt', (r) => console.log('Receipt', r))
  .on('confirmation', (c) => this.handleConfirmation(c, txn));

await signedTxnListener
...

handleConfirmation(c: number, txn: Transaction): void {
  // do some stuff
  if (c >= 3) signedTxnListener.off('confirmation');
}
```