# removeListener in the Listener in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4305314/1754625) question. Is it possible to remove the Listener from inside the callback function?

For example:

```
var callback = function(stream) {
  if(something)
     doSomething();
  else
     server.removeListener('connection', callback);
};
server.on('connection', callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Node's `EventEmitter` class also provide the `once` function, in order to attach a listener which is called... only once.